# How to get book list from amazon clouddrive?

Tags: kindle, amazon

I am sure that this is an obvious question. And that was already asked. But I can not find it. So first I apologize in advance for possible duplicate.

I  have on amazon.com/clouddrive a lot of books. Purchased outside the Amazon (I am polish speaker, and Amazon does not have Polish books). Is there any  convenient (or not...) way to download list of all the books that I have? With titles etc? Some external tool or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the Cloud Drive Application on your own PC (Windows) or Mac (OS/X) *I am not sure if there is a Linux equivalent* then you will have the option to download your cloud drive, (or parts of it), all of your content will be available locally.

You can then view the file and folder names, which is not always very helpful, but you could also consider adding the folder that you download to into a [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) library which will let you browse, search, convert, etc., your content.  Calibre is a free ebook manager that is available for multiple platforms and in multiple languages, *(looking at the statistics the Polish translation is currently at 88% translated but not reviewed)*.

Comment: I did as you wrote;) Thanks. It is a pity that I had to dowload all books (I couldn't do in cloud)